# How to execute raw SQL Query in my Dot net core project? Or how to translate it to Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, .net-core

I'm having a hard time finding anything about executing a raw query,
I have no idea how to translate this to LINQ or if it is even possible.

I have ContactRecords in my DBSet but I don't really want that I guess, I just need to do multiple counts.. raw query..

I need to do multiple COUNTs and use a DB function i created "usp_Parse_domain_name_v5":

This is the Query I'm trying to execute in my DOT NET CORE app:

```
SELECT
    dbo.usp_Parse_domain_name_v5(ContactRecord.URL),
    COUNT(ContactRecord.ContactId) AS TOTAL_IMPRESSIONS,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ContactAttribute.ContactAttributeValue) AS UNIQUE_IMPRESSIONS,
    COUNT(DISTINCT LEADS.LEAD_ID) AS CONVERSIONS,
    MAX(convert(varchar(10), ContactRecord.CallStartDateTime, 102)) AS 'DATE'
FROM
    ContactAttribute 
    LEFT JOIN ContactRecord ON ContactRecord.ContactId = ContactAttribute.ContactId AND ContactAttribute.ContactAttributeName = 'IP'
    LEFT JOIN LEADS 
    ON LEADS.LEAD_ID = ContactRecord.ContactId
    AND LEADS.EMAIL IS NOT NULL AND LEADS.PHONENUMBER IS NOT NULL 
    AND LEADS.FIRSTNAME IS NOT NULL AND LEADS.LASTNAME IS NOT NULL
WHERE
    convert(varchar(10), ContactRecord.CallStartDateTime, 102) = '2019.05.16'
GROUP BY
    dbo.usp_Parse_domain_name_v5(URL)
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(ContactRecord.ContactId) DESC;
```

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12679317/4228458)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to solve with linq? You can also write a stored procedure and call that. That is even easier. If query is too complex I always use strored procedures instead of linq. Here is an example; [Stored Procedure in dot net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525983/stored-procedure-in-dot-net-core)

Comment: Thank alot! I made it because of your comment, I put in my own answer of how I've done it with the stored procedure method.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the selected answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7529020/y-y
definitely helped me!

I created a model and added it to my context:

GatewaysImpressionsAndConversions

```
    public partial class GatewaysImpressionsAndConversions
    {


        public string DOMAIN { get; set; }
        public int TOTAL_IMPRESSIONS { get; set; }
        public int UNIQUE_IMPRESSIONS { get; set; }
        public int CONVERSIONS { get; set; }
        public string DATE { get; set; }
    }
```

**created the Stored procedure too**

and then all i had to do on the controller was:

```
 var result = _context.GatewaysImpressionsAndConversions.FromSql("GetGatewaysImpressionsAndConversionsByDay '2019.05.16'");
            return View("Statistics", await result.ToListAsync());
```

and in my view at the top: 
`@model IEnumerable <YOURCONTEXT.Models.GatewaysImpressionsAndConversions>`

and then the loop:

```
 <table class="table" style="display: none" id="results">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Domain
                </th>
                <th>
                    Total Impressions
                </th>
                <th>
                    Unique Impressions
                </th>
                <th>
                    Conversions
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.DOMAIN</td>
                    <td>@item.TOTAL_IMPRESSIONS</td>
                    <td>@item.UNIQUE_IMPRESSIONS</td>
                    <td>@item.CONVERSIONS</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thanks alot! If it wasn't for @Y.Y's answer I would be hitting my head on a wall right now.

Hope this helps someone else in need,

Best regards